# Suspend issues with nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend

This issue occurs after switching to the `nvidia-driver-470` driver on a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10, but I have been experiencing it in some form since at least 20.10, without being able to find any solution.

When I suspend my system via either the "Suspend" button on the top bar, `sytemctl suspend` or my laptop's sleep button, after the screen first goes black the desktop and the suspend login screen are briefly shown in succession, and only then the screen, power LED and fan turn off like normally.

The timing of the brief "fake resume" is not consistent: sometimes it only shows the login screen, sometimes it stops the suspension until briefly after I login.

When resuming after this has happened, the login screen appears as normal, but I have to wait for any internet connection to restart, and my second screen remains blacks despite it being detected and the display mode remaining on "join displays", until I change the display mode back and forth to fix it.

These issues persist (with slightly altered timing) if I switch to an older proprietary driver (I tried `nvidia-driver-390` and `nvidia-driver-460`), but do not appear while using the `nouveau` driver.

My hardware:

```
lshw -short

H/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         N551JK (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
/0                          bus            N551JK
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/8                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
/0/8/9                      memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/8/a                      memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/8/b                      memory         6MiB L3 cache
/0/c                        memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/c/0                      memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/c/1                      memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/c/2                      memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
/0/c/3                      memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/100                      bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
/0/100/1                    bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
/0/100/1/0                  display        GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M]
/0/100/2                    display        4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/3                    multimedia     Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
/0/100/14                   bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
/0/100/14/0      usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1               generic        SAMSUNG_Android
/0/100/14/0/3               input          2.4G Wireless Mouse
/0/100/14/0/5               communication  Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
/0/100/14/0/7               multimedia     USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam
/0/100/14/1      usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                   communication  8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/1a                   bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
/0/100/1a/1      usb1       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/1/1               bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub
/0/100/1b                   multimedia     8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                   bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c.1                 bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2
/0/100/1c.2                 bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.2/0    wlp4s0     network        AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1c.3                 bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
/0/100/1c.3/0               generic        RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.3/0.1  enp5s0f1   network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1d                   bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
/0/100/1d/1      usb2       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1               bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub
/0/100/1f                   bridge         HM86 Express LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                 storage        8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1f.3                 bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/1                        system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/2                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/3                        system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/4                        generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/5                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/6                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/7                        generic        PnP device ETD0108
/0/9                        generic        PnP device ATK3001
/0/a                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/b                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/d             scsi2      storage        
/0/d/0.0.0       /dev/sda   disk           1TB HGST HTS541010A9
/0/d/0.0.0/1     /dev/sda1  volume         503GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/d/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2  volume         427GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/e             scsi4      storage        
/0/e/0.0.0       /dev/sdb   disk           500GB Samsung SSD 860
/0/e/0.0.0/1     /dev/sdb1  volume         900MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/e/0.0.0/2     /dev/sdb2  volume         100MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/e/0.0.0/3     /dev/sdb3  volume         128MiB reserved partition
/0/e/0.0.0/4     /dev/sdb4  volume         333GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/e/0.0.0/5     /dev/sdb5  volume         582MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/e/0.0.0/6     /dev/sdb6  volume         130GiB EXT4 volume
```

Comment: Maybe there is a software (driver) workaround for the issue but this is more likely a UEFI ("BIOS") problem. It's supposed to have been corrected at least since UEFI ("BIOS") version 202. But go ahead and update it to last version 205 (2019): https://www.asus.com/latin/SupportOnly/N551JK/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: @Nmath Ok, I will do just that. Thank you for the feedback.